# Turning NodeList into unique Array not working

Tags: javascript

Im trying to get a list of names from HTML elements (placeDescription) to generate a dropdown from it and dont need the duplicates.
So I first get "bereiche" which is a nodelist and then convert it into an array and then to a set.
But its not working the duplicates remain and I would like to know why ?
Is there a simpler way to get my nodelist into an array without duplicates ?
This should be very simple but i tried several things now and they are not working.
The javascript is enough the html would not help Im sure.
Thank you.

```js
var bereiche = document.querySelectorAll(".placeDescription889");   
var berArr = Array.from(bereiche);
var setz = new Set(berArr);

let unique =  Array.from(setz); 

console.log(unique.length + "uniquelaenge");
```

Comment: Um, so, DOM elements cannot be duplicates.  An Element cannot belong to more than one parent in the DOM.  The DOM is a tree structure.  So while you may see "duplicated data" potentially, I can assure you the elements, themselves, are not duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The duplicates remain because each *node* in the list is unique. You're creating a set of the *nodes*, not a set of the names. If you want just the names, map the node list to the innerText (or whatever attribute contains the text you're looking for) and create a set from that:

```js
const berArr = Array.from(bereiche, (x) => x.innerText);
const unique = [...new Set(berArr)];
```

Comment: Thank you Sir ! That is the solution. Have a nice weekend.